# Prove a spherical symmetrical integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove this integral result:

$$\iiint_B\frac{\rho(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})}{\vert (x,y,z) - (0,0,z_0) \vert}\,dV=\frac{m}{z_0}$$

where $z_0\gt R$, $B = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2 \le R^2  \}$, and $R$ is the radius of a sphere.

Also $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, so $\rho=\rho(r)$

The mass is given by

$$ m= 4\pi\int_0^R\rho(r)r^2\,dr$$

Answer (score 1):

Express the integral in spherical coordinates,

$$I = \iiint_B\frac{\rho(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})}{\vert (x,y,z) - (0,0,z_0) \vert}\,dV$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^R\int_0^\pi \frac{\rho(r)}{\sqrt{z_0^2+r^2-2z_0r\cos\theta}}r^2dr\sin\theta d\theta$$

Integrate over $\theta$ first to prove the result,

$$I=2\pi\int_0^R \frac{\rho(r)}{rz_0} \left(\sqrt{z_0^2+r^2-2z_0r\cos\theta}\right)_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi} r^2dr$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^R \frac{\rho(r)}{rz_0} \left[(z_0+r)-(z_0-r)\right] r^2dr$$

$$=4\pi\int_0^R \frac{\rho(r)}{z_0} r^2dr=\frac{m}{z_0}$$